# How to execute temporary tables stored procedure in SSIS Packages in result sets

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working on a SSIS package in which we need to execute a stored procedure in OLE DB Source and destination of stored procedure data is Excel. The problem is that the stored procedure contains temporary tables and not get data from the stored procedure need to be suggestion a best fit solution for this.

Trying to execute temporary tables stored procedures in OLE DB Source and get them data into Excel destination

Comment: *"The problem is that store procedure contains temporary tables and not get data from store procedure"* This statement makes no sense. Why does it matter if the procedure uses temporary tables?

Comment: *"how to execute temporary tables"* This makes even less sense, you don't `EXECUTE` a `TABLE`, temporary or not.

Comment: then why in SSIS package not load data from store procedure

Comment: We don't know, you've supplied no information. Perhaps it errored?

Answer (score 2):

SSIS 2012+ does not work well with stored procedures that have temporary tables in them as it cannot determine the metadata and SSIS is exceptionally particular about metadata.

The resolution then is to use the [WITH RESULT SETS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#m-using-execute-to-redefine-a-single-result-set) with the procedure call itself

```
EXECUTE FUNLOAD.BUSMXjob
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
        P1 char(4)
    ,   P5 char(4)
    ,   P9 char(50)
    ,   P59 char(1)
    ,   P60 char(45)
    ,   P105 char(1)
    ,   P106 char(50)
    ,   P156 char(1)
    ,   P157 char(2)
    ,   P159 char(7)
    ,   P166 char(1)
    )
);
```

Now you can use the Stored Procedure within a data flow as the engine is able to correctly deduce the metadata types (because you explicitly defined them).

Comment: im also using this on SSIS but not able to get data from store procedure . A store procedure is very complex and contains more temp tables

Comment: I have some 100 odd packages, with 1 to many source stored procedures which have a multitude of temp tables in them, using `WITH RESULT SETS`, and I assure you this does work. If the issue is you're not getting the data from the stored procedure, then it would seem the stored procedure may be at fault. Edit your question to supply the procedure and preferably, a corresponding table definition for all the actors involved.